# filter unique properties from array of objects with unique values if existing then override the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I am trying to iterate array of objects with different properties. where I am adding objects dynamically and want to check whether the property of the object is exist in the array then only override the value else add it to the array.

For e.x.

```
var arr = [
            {"value":"abc"},
            {"type":"def"},
            {"status":"ghi"},
            {"value":"xyz"}
            ]
```

expected result:

```
arr = [
            {"value":"xyz"},
            {"type":"def"},
            {"status":"ghi"}
```

]

What I am trying so far is not working. Here is my code:

```
var arr = [
            {"value":"abc"},
            {"type":"def"},
            {"status":"ghi"},
            {"value":"abc"}
            ]
            var obj={};
            var key1 = "type", value="xyz";
            obj[key1] = value;
            var newarr = arr.filter(function(entry,i) {
                if (!entry.hasOwnProperty(key1)) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            newarr.push(obj);
```

Please note, the obj will be dynamic so my code is working fine for first time when the property of key1 doesn't change. once I change the value of key1 from "type" to "status", It is adding objects 2 times.

Can anybody help me around this?

Comment: how does `type` mutate to `data-type`? or are the two different?

Comment: typo corrected!!

Comment: what happens with the two `value` keys and an update?

Comment: unique properties with values should be there only.

Comment: please change the example.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have changed my code as per example. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151943/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-dipesh-raichana).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function and [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method.

1. `array#reduce()` used to recreate with new array
2. `Object.keys()` get the key  of the each object .[`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) create the array of all object keys .
3. Then match if not [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in the array then push with new array

**Updated**  replace the `type` with new one `value`

```js
var arr = [{"value":"abc"}, {"type":"def"}, {"status":"ghi"}, {"value":"xyz"}];
    var key1 = "type";
    var value="xyz";
            
   var  result = arr.reduce((a,b) =>{
    if(!a.map(i=> Object.keys(i)[0]).includes(Object.keys(b)[0]))
    {
   if(b.hasOwnProperty(key1)){
      b[key1]=value
  }
    a.push(b)
    }
    return a}, []);
        
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering sir. can we do this using filter only?

Comment: Filter not do the same job...What the problem with `reduce()`?

Comment: There is no problem with reduce just want to know the difference that can we achieve the same thing by filter/shortest way which seems it is by reduce.

Comment: Filter perform only for simple condition with returning array .its not allow to perform any other array function inside that.Thats why move to `array#reduce` .`Array#reduce` used for more num of complex condition's

Comment: I saw that type has the value "def" where it should have "xyz" - doesn't it?

Comment: see my updated answer.You could replace type value from array reduce function

Comment: thanks. I will have to read doc. for reduce. Thanks for your explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and filter and update all found same key objects.

```js
var array = [{ value: "abc" }, { type: "def" }, { status: "ghi" }, { value: "ddd" }],
    key = "type",
    value = "xyz",
    update = false,
    hash = Object.create(null),
    temp = {};

temp[key] = value;

array.push(temp);
array = array.filter(function (o) {
    var key = Object.keys(o)[0];
    if (!hash[key]) {
        hash[key] = o;
        return true;
    }
    hash[key][key] = o[key];
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using ES6 `Array.prototype.reduce()` and `Object.assign()` functions:

```js
var arr = [{"value":"abc"}, {"type":"def"}, {"status":"ghi"}, {"value":"xyz"}],
    obj = arr.reduce((r,o) => Object.assign(r,o), {}),
    result = Object.keys(obj).map( (k) => { o = {}; o[k]=obj[k]; return o } );
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @DipeshRaichana, as for array of objects - fixed, as for the old value - not true, it gives updated value as expected. Check my update

Comment: I have got the answer. Anyway.. Thanks for answering!!

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the job:

```js
var arr = [
  {"value":"abc"},
  {"type":"def"},
  {"status":"ghi"},
  {"value":"xyz"}
];

var obj = {};
for (i in arr) {
  key = Object.keys(arr[i])[0];
  obj[key] = arr[i][key];
}

console.log(obj);
```